# how to install varnish cache in magento2 using localhost

Tags: magento2, cache, magento2.3.2, varnish

How to install the varnish cache in magento2. I need setup the varnish cache in my system localhost. can anyone please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

> follow these steps:
>
> https://www.cloudways.com/blog/magento-2-varnish-setup/

install varnish cache in Magento store. You need to make some minimal changes in configuration as per store requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily Varnish in **Localhost** by this following link : [Click Here](https://www.varnish-software.com/wiki/content/tutorials/varnish/varnish_ubuntu.html)

**Magento Configuration after Varnish install** on Local Server : [Click Here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/varnish/config-varnish-magento.html)